# Open button do not works properly in downloading with a linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, download, file-extension

There is a section in my site that users can download files. I want that As users push the download button and hit "Open" button instead of "save" button, the download get open with it's own program. For example a pdf file should not en with ms word. Now my problem is that, as a user open the file an XML extension will be added to the download URL!!
For example it should be:
www.mysite.com/inputfile/12.dox
but instead of that, it goes for 
www.mysite.com/inputfile/12.dox.xml

Here is my cod:

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string Manuscript = GridView2.DataKeys[idx].Value.ToString();

        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Manuscript);
        string contenttype = String.Empty;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        switch (ext)
        {

            case ".doc":
                contenttype = "application/msword";
                break;
            case ".docx":
                contenttype = "application/msword";
                break;
            case ".xls":
                contenttype = "application/msexcel";
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                contenttype = "application/msexcel";
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                contenttype = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contenttype = "image/png";
                break;
            case ".gif":
                contenttype = "image/gif";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                contenttype = "application/pdf";
                break;


        }
        Response.ContentType = contenttype;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(Manuscript));
        Response.End(); 

    }
```